# how to pass param to a filter function in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have two questions.

1. how to pass param to a filter function.

   say for example:
   `item in masterData|filter1:masterdata|filter2:outputFromfilter1, myparam | filter3:outputFromfilter2, myparam1,myparam2`
2. how to access the controller `$scope` inside the filter function.

   ```
   animateAppModule.filter( 'distinct' , function(){
       return function(masterdata){
           //HOW TO ACCESS THE $scope HERE
       }
   })
   ```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9t62c/). Pls. look in to the firebug console, to see that the parameters passed to the filter is `undefined`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### For your 1st question:

You can give parameters separated by `:` into the filter.
For example,

```
{{ array | myfilter:a:b:c }}
```

In your filter definition,

```
angular.module('app', []).
  filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(in, param1, param2, param3) {
      // do something
    };
  });
```

#### for your 2nd question.

Not sure why you need to access `$scope`.
Can you simply feed whatever needed information via param as your Q1?

Comment: It looks like working for me (http://plnkr.co/edit/PVSEqp).  You may want to check whether your `distinctGrades` is really defined OK.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i could not pass `$scope` in the param.

Comment: You could pass `this` in the filter as in the expression in the template, `this` is the `$scope` in the controller.  But I do not think it is a good practice as your filter will be dependent on $scope structure/state.